# Declaração de charset no arquivo .css

Tags: css, codificação-de-caracteres

Às vezes me deparo com alguns exemplos de arquivo `.css` com a declaração de `charset` logo na primeira linha:

```
@charset "utf-8";
```

Até meu editor de códigos (Dreamweaver CC 2015), quando crio um novo arquivo CSS, já coloca essa linha por padrão no início do documento:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas um arquivo CSS geralmente apenas contém estilos e propriedades (exceto em casos de pseudo-elementos `::before` e `::after` onde se pode colocar textos na propriedade `content`).

Me surgiu uma dúvida em relação a isso: realmente é necessária essa declaração? Se *sim* ou *não*, qual o motivo?

Comment: Pergunta complementar: [Operadores CSS com @](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/263028/70)

Comment: Sabe se existe alguma diferença entre declarar no HTML ou CSS?  ` <meta charset="utf-8" />` ?

Comment: @hugocsl Pois é, essa é minha dúvida. Qual seria a explicação técnica pra isso? :D

Comment: Vou dar uma pesquisada, mas uma vez que um eh indexado dentro do outro acho que declarar no html seria mais prudente... Mas vou pesquisar antes tbm sobre isso

Comment: Algo que está relacionado, se não responder em parte à questão é colocar estilos como  `.cabeçalho { }` num css sem `@charset` ? Como o browser deve interpretar esse nome uma vez que está fora do ascii normal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Palavras da W3C**

> You should always use `UTF-8` as the character encoding of your style sheets and your HTML pages, and declare that encoding in your HTML. **If you do that, there is no need to declare the encoding of your style sheet**.

PORTUGUÊS:
*"Você deve sempre usar `UTF-8` como a codificação de caracteres de suas folhas de estilo e suas páginas HTML e declarar essa codificação em seu HTML. **Se você fizer isso, não há necessidade de declarar a codificação da sua folha de estilos.**"*

*Fonte:* https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-css-charset

Então resumidamente podemos dizer que se vc já declarou o `Charset` no HTML que vai indexar essa folha de estilo vc não precisa necessariamente declarar o `Charset` dentro do `.CSS`

Para declarar o Charset no HTML vc pode usar:

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

Ou

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=IANAcharset">
```

**Leve também esses pontos em consideração:**

- Esse elemento `<meta>` é apenas uma parte do algoritmo para determinar o conjunto de caracteres de uma página que os navegadores aplicam. O cabeçalho `HTTP Content-Type` e quaisquer elementos da `BOM` têm precedência sobre esse elemento.
- É uma boa prática, e altamente recomendável, definir o conjunto de caracteres usando este atributo.
- várias técnicas de scripts cruzados poderão prejudicar o usuário da página, como a técnica de `cross-scripting` de *fallback* `UTF-7`. Sempre definindo esta meta irá proteger contra esses riscos.

Então definir o `Charset` no HTML é a té uma questão de segurança e é considerada uma boa prática e altamente recomendável.

Fonte: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta

---

**Veja que a Mozilla diz que:**

> A regra `@charset` especifica a codificação de caracteres utilizada na folha de estilo.

Fonte: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/@charset

**Nota!** Não é suficiente simplesmente colocar `@charset "utf-8";` no topo da folha de estilo - você também precisa salvar sua folha de estilo na codificação de caracteres `UTF-8`.

**Importante:** Como o cabeçalho `HTTP` tem uma precedência mais alta que a declaração `in-document @charset` , você deve sempre levar em consideração se a codificação de caracteres já está declarada no cabeçalho HTTP. Se estiver, `@charset`
deve ser definido para declarar a mesma codificação e só terá efeito quando a folha de estilo for lida em um contexto onde não haja cabeçalhos HTTP (por exemplo, de uma unidade local).

Answer (score -2):

Quando iniciei tive vários problemas com acentuação, e pesquisando, descobri a necessidade de informar qual tipo de codificação que o navegador irá utilizar, nesse caso, o utf-8.

Answer (score -3):

no CSS eu uso o charset assim:

```
html:lang(pt-br) { 
    @charset "UTF-8"; 
}
```